# jquery data loads oonce only not working again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jquery method to load data when selects from the dropdown but the problem is that when i click and select and data changes then again when I select it is not working anymore

Please take a look at below snippet what i have done so far

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="ht_opt"]').change(function() { 
   var tab    = $('select[name="ht_opt"]').val();
   var symbol = $('#symbol').val();
   if ($(this).val()){
   var dropdown = "<select name='ht_opt'><option>Balance Sheet</option><option>Profit and Loss Account</option><option>Cash Flow Statement</option></select>";
     
     $('#ht_title').html(tab + " " + dropdown);
     $('#ht_data').html(symbol);
    }
   }  
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="inf_h2" id="ht_title">Balance Sheet
  <select name="ht_opt">
   <option>Balance Sheet</option>
   <option>Profit and Loss Account</option>
   <option>Cash Flow Statement</option>
  </select>
</h2>
<input type="hidden" id="symbol" value="test Symbol" />

<div id="ht_data">
</div>
```

[**`Demo fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/nc425yh1/)

Comment: where is your code or can we just answer questions to any code we like?

Comment: I have attached fiddle

Comment: your code contain extra }

Comment: This code doesn't do anything ... at least I cannot see it

Comment: @devnull69 you are not been able to see the code really ?

Comment: I see the code, but there is no action on change of the dropdown. You said it is working once... not for me

Comment: yeah the thing is that whehn you click it will run once

Comment: it doesn't run. You said you removed the extra `}` which you just didn't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of jquery .because you are append the `select` tag on each time of the `change` function .

Just follow the `@devnull69` comment below use the first option like this `<option style='color:#ccc'>--select option--</option>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change','select[name="ht_opt"]',function() {
      var tab = $(this).val();
      var symbol = $('#symbol').val();
      if ($(this).val()) {
        var dropdown = "<select name='ht_opt'><option style='color:#ccc'>--select option--</option><option>Balance Sheet</option><option>Profit and Loss Account</option><option>Cash Flow Statement</option></select>";

        $('#ht_title').html(tab + " " + dropdown);
        $('#ht_data').html(symbol);
      }
    
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="inf_h2" id="ht_title">Balance Sheet
  <select name="ht_opt">
              <option style="color:#ccc">--select option--</option>
       <option>Balance Sheet</option>
       <option>Profit and Loss Account</option>
       <option>Cash Flow Statement</option>
      </select>
</h2>
<input type="hidden" id="symbol" value="test Symbol" />

<div id="ht_data">
</div>
```

***Updated answer*** : its show the selected value without reproduce the `select` tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="ht_opt"]', function() {
    var tab = $(this).val();
    var symbol = $('#symbol').val();
    $('select[name="ht_opt"] option').removeClass('select')
  $('select[name="ht_opt"] option:selected').addClass('select')
    if (tab) {
      $('#ht_title p').html(tab);
      $('#ht_data').html(symbol);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.select{
background:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="inf_h2" id="ht_title">
  <p>Balance Sheet</p>
  <select name="ht_opt">
           <option class="select">Balance Sheet</option>
           <option>Profit and Loss Account</option>
           <option>Cash Flow Statement</option>
          </select>
</h2>
<input type="hidden" id="symbol" value="test Symbol" />

<div id="ht_data">
</div>
```

Comment: great but when you click on first value again it wont work

Comment: For the first entry to work (after you re-inserted the select) you should add another empty dummy option `<option value="">Please select</option>` as your first option. Otherwise the change won't be detected

Comment: @MarkAlan beacuse each time click the will reproduce the `select` tag.that why is not get the first value.if need ah first value .you dont reproduce the `select` tag on each `onchange` event

Comment: so I have to make one value to be selected once we select that option I should make it to be selected right

Comment: @prasad what if user want to see first data again he ca do it right ? and also how can i make the dropdown to be selected

Comment: Happy to help .. @MarkAlan

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **delegate**.But As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .**on()** method

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').delegate('select[name="ht_opt"]','change', function(){
    var tab    = $('select[name="ht_opt"]').val();
    var symbol = $('#symbol').val();
    if ($(this).val()){
      var dropdown = "<select name='ht_opt'><option>Balance Sheet</option><option>Profit and Loss Account</option><option>Cash Flow Statement</option></select>";
      console.log(dropdown);
      $('#ht_title').html(tab + " " + dropdown);
      $('#ht_data').html(symbol);
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="inf_h2" id="ht_title">Balance Sheet
  <select name="ht_opt">
    <option>Balance Sheet</option>
    <option>Profit and Loss Account</option>
    <option>Cash Flow Statement</option>
  </select>
</h2>
<input type="hidden" id="symbol" value="test Symbol" />

<div id="ht_data">
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/nc425yh1/9/